# How to convert thumbnail generation rule from paperclip to carrierwave

Tags: paperclip, carrierwave

I am migrating from Paperclip to Carrierwave. Here I am trying to convert the processing commands for thumbnail generations:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
    styles: {
      thumb: '220x140#',
      big: '620x600>',
      no_proportion: '255x162!'
    },
    convert_options: {
      all: '-strip',
      thumb: '-delete 1--1',
      no_proportion: '-delete 1--1'
    }
```

I am planning to use MiniMagick. I got that I convert from `220x140#` to `resize_to_fill(220,140)`, but I am not sure how to convert all the other commands.

P.S. It would be better if I can reuse the existing ImageMagick commands and parameters, even for resizing (i.e. not using built-in helper resizer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the following. However I am not sure if it is totally equivalent.

```
  process :strip

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [220,140]
  end
  version :mobile do
    process :resize_to_fill => [320,210]
  end
  version :mobile_small do
    process :resize_to_fill => [256,168]
  end
  version :big do
    process :resize_to_limit => [620,600]
  end
  version :groupbuy_ad do
    process :resize_to_fill => [96,60]
  end
  version :email do
    process :resize_to_fill => [125,125]
  end
  version :widget_165 do
    process :resize_to_fill => [165,105]
  end
  version :widget_100 do
    process :resize_to_fill => [100,64]
  end
  version :no_proportion do
    process :resize => '255x162!'
  end

  def strip
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.strip
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end

  def resize(dimension)
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.resize dimension
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end

  def get_first_frame
    manipulate! do |img|
      img = img.delete '1--1'
    end
  end
```